# Fortify : DOM based cross site scripting

Tags: javascript, html, fortify

I have a fortify vulnerability Cross site scripting : DOM.

In my application(asp.net) we are dynamically constructing html and assign it to a div tag where it is complaining as issue.

```
str += '<div id="' + itemID + '"';

if(somecondition==true){

  str += 'class="' + somevalue + '"';  

  }

if (somevalue == 0) {            

  str += ' style="position: relative; ';

  str += 'top:0; ' ;

  str += 'visibility: inherit; '

  }else{

  str += ' style="position: absolute; ';

  str += 'top: ' +  itemY + '; ' ;

  str += 'width: ' + w + '; ';

  str += 'height: ' + h + '; '

  str += 'visibility: inherit; '
```

....

......

after constructing the html, we are assigning it to a div tag as below.

```
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

  document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0).appendChild(newDiv);

  newDiv.innerHTML = str;
```

while assigning str to the newDiv fortify is showing it as a Cross site scripting : DOM issue.

To fix this issue I tried using html encoder but it didnt work. Please share your inputs to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Simply HTML encoding the data is not sufficient.  Make sure that the unsafe data is encoded properly for the context in which it appears within the document. See the following articles, which discuss the various contexts and the importance of context-sensitive encoding:

1. http://security.coverity.com/document/2013/Mar/fixing-xss-a-practical-guide-for-developers.html
2. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score -1):

A library like DOMPurify might be all you need to address those security concerns.